# Getting search results not based on a whole indexed value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm using ThinkingSphinx for a simple searching which goes through Book model. my book_indexes.rb looks like this:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :book, with: :active_record do
  indexes title
  indexes author
  indexes publishing_date
  indexes isbn
end
```

and controller action looks like this

```
  def index
    @books = Book.search(params[:search])
  end
```

so far everything works as it is supposed, when i type "bible" it returns Book titled "Bible". But is it possible to get search result which are not based eg on a whole title? In more simple words i would like to get "bible" whenever i search for "bib" or "b".

EDIT

my thinking_sphinx.yml is now:

```
development:
  enable_star: true
  min_infix_len: 1
  min_prefix_len: 1
```

and controller action:

```
@books = Book.search("*#{params[:search]}*")
```

but it still works just the same, only without any query, just after loading the page, @books is nil

Comment: You've run `rake ts:index` or `rake ts:rebuild`?

Comment: nope, gonna try in a minute

Comment: yes, thats what i needed to do, i also deleted min_infix_len: 1 from thinking_sphinx.yml because it raised an error saying prefixes and infifes cant be both enabled. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [min_infix_len](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-min-infix-len.html) property. You can set your `thinking_sphinx.yml` configuration settings like this:

```
development:
  #.... truncated ....
  enable_star: true # Allow wildcard searching 
  min_infix_len: 3  # Indexes on values starting at 3 letters like "bib"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking Sphinx allows you to use wildcards so when you search like this instead:

```
@books = Book.search("*#{params[:search]}*")
```

It will also work when you dont use the whole word!

Comment: You'll need to configure enable_star and min_prefix_len for this to work - but that's not hard to do. Both settings are mentioned on this page of the docs: http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/advanced_config.html